# Jenkins GitHub CHecks Plugin: Failed Publishing github checks

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-github-plugin

I'm trying to implement the GitHub Checks Plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-checks/). I followed the guide from here (https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-branch-source-plugin/blob/master/docs/github-app.adoc) but I still get the following message.

[GitHub Checks] Failed Publishing GitHub checks: org.kohsuke.github.HttpException: {"message":"Resource not accessible by integration","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/checks/runs#create-a-check-run"}

In contrast, the GitHub Branch Source (https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-branch-source/) works correctly and I get a notification like: `continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge — This commit looks good`

I also followed the same steps as this guide: https://faun.pub/github-checks-using-jenkins-pipeline-2d8c594dfba9

I'm ruinning a self hosted jenkins server and it is a Multibranch pipeline

Comment: For anyone with the same problem. The solutions was to add: "Checks: Acess: Read and write" permission to the GitHub App.

Comment: Good catch. You can add a detail answer below (with URLs, references and screenshots). And you can accept your own answer.